# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen other questions but the answers seem so complicated and could not understand them so heres my code:

Note:I'm new to language of c shar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Input_Program
{
    class Program
    {
       private static void Main()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my bool program!");
           Console.WriteLine("Input a NON capital y or n when told to.");


            char Y;
            char N;

            if(Y = 'y')
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign: `if(Y == 'y')`

The way you have it right now, it assigns the value `'y'` to `Y`, and this is also the result of the assignment expression. It's a `char`, while the compiler expects a `bool` result.

**Update:**

Of course as thephpdeveloper says, the compiler will also insist that you assign a value to `Y` before reading from it. So:

```
char Y = 'y';
char N = 'n';

if(Y == 'y')
{}
```

Comment: As a quick explanation; if you say if(Y = 'y') {} then you are effectively doing if(Y) which fails since Y is a char and if() requires a boolean.  Just though I'd give a little more insight into the error :)

Comment: Now it says use of unsigned local variable Y.

Comment: It's because that you have not assigned anything to `Y`. Your line `char Y;` only declares the variable, but the variable is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The single `=` is for assignment.  What you are looking for is the equality operator, `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided,

```
(Y = 'y')
```

evaluates to be `'y'` because the new assignment will always be returned as a result of successful assignment. With that, `'y'` cannot be converted into a boolean for comparison in the `if` statement.

`=` is an assignment operator. To compare two values, you should use `==` instead.

Besides that, you need to use `(char)Console.Read()` in order for the program to read in a character from the user input:

```
 char Y = (char) Console.Read();
 if(Y == 'y'){
     Console.WriteLine('You pressed YES.');
 }else{
     Console.WriteLine('You probably pressed NO.');
 }
```